# What is the accepted way to do unit testing in D?

Tags: unit-testing, d

I know D has built-in unit tests, but while they are incredibly useful, they are also very limited, especially when reporting errors. I've been looking at third party tool kits and frameworks, and can't seem to decide between them.

What is the low down about unit testing D programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most everyone just uses the built-in unit testing framework. And if what you're doing is unit testing, it's generally plenty. It's when you're doing more complicated testing - testing beyond making sure that each individual function has the correct output for various inputs - that the built-in unit testing might not be enough - or at least it doesn't provide additional tools to support fancier tests. However, it *does* provide enough to build more complicated testing tools if you want them. Given that `unittest` blocks are essentially just normal functions that get called when the tests are run and given how D has fantastic compile-time reflection, you can do a *lot* inside of a `unittest` block. There just aren't many testing-specific tools provided by the language or standard library. The few that there are can be found in [std.exception](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_exception) - e.g. [`assertThrown`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_exception#assertThrown) and [`assertNotThrown`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_exception#assertNotThrown).

Now, there are folks who think that the built-in unit testing facilities are lacking or who just don't like how they work for one reason or another, so several homegrown unit testing frameworks have been created by folks in the community (many of which - [as DejanLekic points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129453/160887) - can be found on [the D wiki](http://wiki.dlang.org/Libraries_and_Frameworks#Unit_Testing_Framework)), but at this point, most everyone just uses the built-in unit testing facilities.

**EDIT:** As [Михаил Страшун points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128812/what-is-the-accepted-way-to-do-unit-testing-in-d#comment33608799_22142786), [std.typecons](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html) does have basic some facilities for mocking objects if you're looking for something along those lines. e.g.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.AutoImplement
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.BlackHole
http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.WhiteHole

They're excellent examples of what D's compile-time reflection can do and can be used with D's built-in unit testing facilities without needing anything more complicated added to the language or requiring a separate framework.

Comment: https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit also contains a solution to mocking full objects and interfaces.

Comment: Nomad's DUnit is my current favourite for the times where simple asserts no longer cut it. One issue I keep coming across, no matter what unit testing tool I use, is figuring out how to easily run tests, either via dub for a full-project test build, or via rdmd for isolated tests. A little documentation and a few examples can go a long way.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not happy about the way unit-tests are done in D, there are few testing frameworks for D available. Most of them are listed on D wiki: http://wiki.dlang.org/Libraries_and_Frameworks#Unit_Testing_Framework .

Comment: Is there any one framework that is preferred over others? Any one I should avoid?

Answer (score 1):

Dicebot caught me on IRC and we had a lengthy talk about testing D programs. The gist was that there's a very strong focus in the D community about sticking to the built in testing facilities, and that most unit test frameworks go largely unused. In his own words:

> Anything more fancy than assert helpers I would probably not recommend
>   (like not-fatal assertions or using classes as test blocks), but
>   within just tweaking printed messages, feel free to experiment.

Comment: Ask people who test software for living - they will probably agree with the belief that D's unittests are too limited. One definitely needs extra framework to do the job right.

Comment: My "first language" being Ruby (an ecosystem with a very strong focus on testing everything), I want to agree. I want isolated tests with fixtures and mocks and better feedback. I want TDD and BDD and the kitchen sink. However, if the rest of the ecosystem doesn't agree, I'll just end up depending on unmaintained code.

Comment: @mkaito Personally, I wouldn't consider mock stuff to be part of unit testing. That moves more into component testing territory, which is certainly quite important, but it's a level beyond unit testing and not the sort of thing that is directly supported by the language, and it never will be. However, if someone comes up with something good enough, tools to support mocking stuff up could end up in the standard library, as could other, fancier testing tools, but that hasn't happened yet, and it wouldn't end up in the language itself regardless.

Comment: There are some tools for mocking support in Phobos : http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.AutoImplement or http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.BlackHole

Comment: @МихаилСтрашун Good catch. I'd forgotten about those, though I suspect that someone looking for a full-on mocking framework will want more than those. They are however an excellent starting point.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis I consider mocking to be an essential part of unit testing and the only real way to test 'units' in isolation. Also https://github.com/nomad-software/dunit has full (and very easy to use) mocking support.